# python парсер зависает после ошибки 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: linux, python-3.x, http, парсер, requests

Написал простенький парсер на Python 3.5.2. Код примерно такой:

```
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import csv
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(levelname)s in \'%(module)s\' at line %(lineno)d: %(message)s',
                datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                level=logging.DEBUG,
                filename='requests.log')
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

with open(outFile, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow('бла1', 'бла2', ...)
    # ...
    for id in range(firstId, lastId):
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
            r.raise_for_status()
            # проверки, получение инфы, запись в csv...
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(str(e))
        # some code...
```

Иногда сайт, на который посылаются запросы возвращает 500 ошибку. Ошибка записывается в log-файл. Но после этого программа зависает: выполнение скрипта все ещё висит в процессах, однако новые строки не появляются ни в лог файле, ни в файле результатов, и время работы процесса в `ps aux | grep python3` не изменяется.

Повторить зависание бросая 500-ю ошибку в ручную, не получилось.

Скрипт запускается на серверах DigitalOcean: 512 MB / 20 GB Disk / Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 командой `nohup python3 main.py &`.

Также запускал скрипт со своего личного ноута на Debain 8 Jessie обычным запуском скрипта (т.е. без nohup, без фонового режима), и также получал ошибку 500, но на моем компе скрипт не зависал.

Answer (score 1):

Да тут зависать особо нечему. Многопоточность + блокировки в коде не используются - дедлоков нет. Никаких вечных циклов нет.

Единственное потенциальное место для зависаний - это

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

Поставьте там [таймаут на ожидание ответа и на чтение](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts)

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
```

Так-же, если процесс повис, можно попробовать посмотреть на каком системном вызове он повис при помощи `strace`

```
strace -s 99 -ffp 12345
```

12345 - PID